# What SQL Statements Will Normalize and Cleanse this table

Tags: postgresql

What we are trying to achieve is some level of cleansing on the table. This is what we currently have (this a subset of the table please)

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
| STUDENTNO |  LASTNAME  | FIRSTNAME | PREFERNAME | GENDER |  COURSE   |    YEAR    | MAJOR |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
| auaw64    | Drury      | Janet     | Jane       | f      | DIPLOMA   | 29/10/2011 | NO    |
| auaw64    | Drury      | Janet     | Jane       | f      | BACHELORS | 29/09/2013 | YES   |
| auqn70    | Givens     | Jason     |            | m      | DIPLOMA   | 29/10/2011 | NO    |
| auqn70    | Givens     | Jason     |            | m      | BACHELORS | 10/10/2012 | YES   |
| mrpd90    | Blackstock | Williams  | Bill       | m      | DIPLOMA   | 29/10/2011 | NO    |
| mrpd90    | Blackstock | Williams  | Bill       | m      | BACHELORS | 29/09/2013 | YES   |
| pyts84    | Peters     | Theresa   |            | f      | BACHELORS | 29/09/2013 | YES   |
| qjgp97    | Aaron      | Felina    |            | f      | DIPLOMA   | 29/10/2013 | NO    |
| qzhs28    | Gyeong     | Ma        |            | f      | DIPLOMA   | 29/10/2011 | NO    |
| qzhs28    | Gyeong     | Ma        |            | f      | BACHELORS | 29/09/2013 | YES   |
| uwnv95    | Anholt     | Wilhemina |            | f      | MASTERS   | 29/10/2011 | NO    |
| uwnv95    | Anholt     | Wilhemina |            | f      | BACHELORS | 10/10/2012 | YES   |
| jaiw67    | Muguruza   | David     | Dave       | m      | MASTERS   | 28/09/2014 | YES   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

But we need to reorder this table with the 'studentno' as the new primary key and then perform an update/upsert (which is where the new columns have now emerged)

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| STUDENTNO |  LASTNAME  | FIRSTNAME | PREFERNAME | GENDER | MAJOR_COURSE | MAJOR_YEAR | MINOR_COURSE | MINOR_YEAR |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| auaw64    | Drury      | Janet     | Jane       | f      | BACHELORS    | 29/09/2013 | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2011 |
| auqn70    | Givens     | Jason     |            | m      | BACHELORS    | 10/10/2012 | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2011 |
| mrpd90    | Blackstock | Williams  | Bill       | m      | BACHELORS    | 29/09/2013 | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2011 |
| pyts84    | Peters     | Theresa   |            | f      | BACHELORS    | 29/09/2013 | null         | null       |
| qjgp97    | Aaron      | Felina    |            | f      | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2013 | null         | null       |
| qzhs28    | Gyeong     | Ma        |            | f      | BACHELORS    | 29/09/2013 | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2011 |
| uwnv95    | Anholt     | Wilhemina |            | f      | BACHELORS    | 29/09/2013 | DIPLOMA      | 29/10/2011 |
| jaiw67    | Muguruza   | David     | Dave       | m      | MASTERS      | 28/09/2014 | null         | null       |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Essentially we want to take the first table and convert to the second but doing this using the functionalities inside PostgreSQL and also turning the 'studentno' into the unique key. We can then write the new table into another for another app to read or make use of but the new key will now offer a proper query handle unlike we have in the original table.

Comment: Adding a column for second course will certainly make that table even more  not normalized. You need to change the design, student's gender certainly shouldn't be anywhere near the commencement date.

Comment: Are you certain that a given student can have only 2 course types?

Comment: As Jakub said: adding a second column **de**-normalizes this design

Comment: Homework assignment? The table structure is pretty dire, making me think it might be.

Comment: Thanks guys, we already have a faulty design that creates two distinct rows or three (not more than three) for the same student id. We want to join such duplicates into a single row and be able to attach the two (or three courses with commencement dates) to the same student such that when we query the new table with the ID (which now is the primary key) we can see just one row and all courses.

Comment: @CraigRinger. It is not assignment really. We actually have a much bigger table. I just took out those. Agreed that gender is not important, really. But I just took some of the relevant columns out. We still have columns as DOB, Nationality, Addresses and all sort. But we just want to express each student as a unique person and attach the courses in one row and eliminate the duplication based on courses. But SQL is not my forte. I am a pure architect.

Comment: @OFA That's doubling down on the faulty design. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization . Do *not* try to jam everything into single wide rows. You need multiple tables, and joins.

Comment: @OFA as already written multiple times in the comments here, you need more tables to normalize, see my answer below on how your courses can be separated from personal data like gender, addresses etc. and linked with them, so you can join the tables to get all courses for your students

Answer (score 2):

First create the course table

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (
id SERIAL,
course varchar);
```

Then insert all courses into the new table

```
insert into Courses(course)
select course from Participants GROUP BY course
```

Then create the n-n relation table

```
CREATE TABLE Participants_Courses (
    id SERIAL,
    studentno varchar,
    course integer,
    year date,
    major boolean);
```

Then insert the values from Participants into the n-n table

```
INSERT INTO Participants_Courses AS PC (studentno, course, year,major)
VALUES (SELECT STUDENTNO, (SELECT id FROM Courses AS C  where PC.course = C.course), YEAR, MAJOR);
```

Finally drop the unnecessary columns from the Participants table

```
ALTER TABLE Participants DROP COLUMN course;
ALTER TABLE Participants DROP COLUMN year;
ALTER TABLE Participants DROP COLUMN major;
```

This is normalized, I would not recommend to insert two courses into the same column of the table, because it would limit you. With this, a person could have many courses.
This is the Third normal form, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

I did not test the SQL's so there may be syntax errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

Doing this is completely backwards and wrong. It's doubling down on a bad table design by making it into a worse one. Do *not* use wide, denormalized tables as your primary data store.

Read:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

and get familiar with using joins.

If you use this solution then I am sorry to whoever has to maintain the code later. You appear to be determined to do it, and there are legitimate reasons you might want to make this transformation for things like a view or report, so here's how.

---

Use a self-left-join, treating studentno as the key. Something like:

```
select 
  l."STUDENTNO", l."LASTNAME", l."FIRSTNAME", l."PREFERNAME", l."GENDER", 
  l."COURSE" AS "MAJOR_COURSE", l."YEAR" AS "MAJOR_YEAR",
  r."COURSE" AS "MINOR_COURSE", r."YEAR" AS "MINOR_YEAR"
FROM table1 l
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 r
  ON (l."STUDENTNO" = r."STUDENTNO" 
      AND (l."COURSE", l."YEAR") <> (r."COURSE", r."YEAR"))
WHERE (l."COURSE", l."YEAR") < (r."COURSE", r."YEAR") 
   OR r."COURSE" IS NULL;
```

A proper solution wouldn't rely on the lexical sort of `BACHELORS` before `DIPLOMA` and would instead use a `CASE` statement or a function to produce proper ordering, but since we're already piling wrong on top of wrong, it doesn't matter much.

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f49f/1

Now. Delete this, and go do it properly. Create a `STUDENT` table and `COURSE` table, and a `STUDENT_COURSE` table that joins them and records which students took which courses in which years. It's relational databases 101.